What is $y$ in theorem 9.24 Rudin's PMA?

9.24 Theorem Suppose $\mathbf{f}$ is a $\mathscr{C}^{\prime}$-mapping of an open set $E \subset R^n$ into $R^n, \mathbf{f}^{\prime}(\mathbf{a})$ is invertible for some $\mathbf{a} \in E$, and $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$. Then
(a) there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ in $R^n$ such that $\mathbf{a} \in U, \mathbf{b} \in V, \mathbf{f}$ is one-toone on $U$, and $\mathbf{f}(U)=V$;
(b) if $\mathbf{g}$ is the inverse of $\mathbf{f}[$ which exists, by $(a)]$, defined in $V$ by
$$
\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbf{x} \quad(\mathbf{x} \in U)
$$
then $\mathbf{g} \in \mathscr{C}^{\prime}(V)$.
Writing the equation $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ in component form, we arrive at the following interpretation of the conclusion of the theorem: The system of $n$ equations
$$
y_i=f_1\left(x_1, \ldots, x_n\right) \quad(1 \leq i \leq n)
$$
can be solved for $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in terms of $y_1, \ldots, y_n$, if we restrict $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ to small enough neighborhoods of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$; the solutions are unique and continuously differentiable.
Proof
(a) Put $\mathbf{f}^{\prime}(a)=A$, and choose $\lambda$ so that
$$
2 \lambda\left\|A^{-1}\right\|=1
 \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (46)$$
Since $\mathbf{f}^{\prime}$ is continuous at a, there is an open ball $U \subset E$, with center at a, such that
$$
\left\|\mathbf{f}^{\prime}(\mathbf{x})-A\right\|<\lambda \quad(\mathbf{x} \in U) .
 \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (47)$$
We associate to each $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ a function $\varphi$, defined by
$$\varphi(x) = x + A^{-1}(y - f(x)) \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (48)$$
$(x \in E)$.
Note that $f(x) = y$ if and only if $x$ is a fixed point of $\varphi$.
Since $\varphi'(x) = I - A^{-1}f'(x) = A^{-1}(A - f'(x))$, $(46)$ and $(47)$ imply
that
$$\left\|\varphi^{\prime}(\mathbf{x})\right\|<\frac{1}{2} \quad(\mathbf{x} \in U)  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (49) .$$ Hence
$$\left|\varphi\left(\mathbf{x}_1\right)-\varphi\left(\mathbf{x}_2\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}\left|\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2\right| \quad\left(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2 \in U\right)
 \ \ \  \ (50)$$



We associate to each $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ a function $\varphi$, defined by
$$\varphi(x) = x + A^{-1}(y - f(x)) \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (48)$$
$(x \in E)$.

I have so many questions there, what is "$y$" is it a constant ? or does it depend on $x$? Is it arbitrary? If so why do we even bother to write it down ? If it is not  arbitrary what is it ? Is it a variable ? if so how did we differentiate $\varphi$? If I am not mistaken $f'$ usually means  that the total derivative.

$y$ does not depend on $x$, it's any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but the dependence is between $\varphi$ and $y$: you can think of the assignment here as a mapping $y \mapsto \varphi_y$, with $\varphi_y : x \mapsto x + A^{-1}(y - f(x))$, just without the indexation by $y$. Thus you only differentiate $\varphi$ in regards to $x$, in particular.
Often an author might get rid of the indexation I introduced when it is not necessary to make different $y$s interact between each other. For example, if you were to, I don't know, study the continuity of the function $y \mapsto \varphi_y$ in some function space (not the best examle but you get the picture I'm sure), then you'd need a different notation for $\varphi$ for each $y$ since otherwise you're using different objects named the same, which would be very confusing.
Since there's nothing of the sort going on, you don't really need to have a different notation for each $y$ since you study each $y$ separately, and thus many authors will just do like Rudin did here.

So $\varphi$ is a function in 2 variables $x,y$?

@Mathematicsenjoyer $\varphi$ is a function of one variable, $x$. $\varphi$ itself depends on $y$.

What is the difference between depends on $y$ and a function of $y$?

@Mathematicsenjoyer The gist of it is that you could and might as well see $\varphi$ as a function of $f$, $A$, $y$ and $x$, but out of these four variables you only really care about it being a function of $x$ for what you are doing.
